# Mimic `super` keyword: Set `base` class and `derived` class field during instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, super

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Parent {
  int baseA_ = 0;
  double baseB_ = 0.0;

  Parent() = default;
  virtual ~Parent() = default;

  Parent(int a) : baseA_{a} {}

  Parent(int a, double b) : baseA_{a}, baseB_{b} {}

  auto set(int a) -> void { baseA_ = a; }

  auto set(int a, double b) -> void {
    baseA_ = a;
    baseB_ = b;
  }
};

struct AnotherParent {
  std::string baseA_ = {};

  AnotherParent() = default;
  virtual ~AnotherParent() = default;

  AnotherParent(const std::string &a) : baseA_{a} {}

  auto set(const std::string &a) -> void { baseA_ = a; }
};

// Notice that the `Child` class inherits from T.
template <typename T>
struct Child : public T {
  int derivedA_ = 0;

  Child() = default;
  ~Child() = default;

  Child(int a) : derivedA_{a} {}

  auto super(auto... args) -> Child & {
    T::set(args...);
    return (*this);
  }
};

int main() {
  auto c1 = Child<Parent>(23).super(23, 3.5);
  auto c2 = Child<AnotherParent>(243).super("Hello, World!");

  std::cout << "C1 - Base -> A: " << c1.baseA_ << ", B: " << c1.baseB_
            << std::endl;
  std::cout << "C1 - Derived -> A: " << c1.derivedA_ << std::endl;

  std::cout << "C2 - Base -> A: " << c2.baseA_ << std::endl;
  std::cout << "C2 - Derived -> A: " << c2.derivedA_ << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

To compile use:

> g++ -std=c++17 -fconcepts Main.cpp

or

> g++ -std=c++14 -fconcepts Main.cpp

### What I want to achieve?

I want to initialize both child class (inherited from template class type) and parent class fields during instantiation. I don't want to pass a parent class object as parameter to constructor.

### Pros:

1. It can be used to set `super class` (i mean it) data fields for any type.
2. It offers safety by producing a `compiler-error` if `set()` method is not suitable.
3. No need to overload child class constructor to set `super class` data fields
   (Infact, no one can overload child class constructor to match any super class, or is it possible?, I am not sure).
4. Call to `super()` is optional.

### Limitations:

1. Works for single inheritance only, although interfaces can be implemented.
2. Parent class should have a `set()` method.

### Queries:

1. The way how I implemented `super` - Is is a good practice?
2. Are there any hidden cons?
3. Does it violate any idiom?
4. Is is ok to use `-fconcepts`?
5. If it is good, can it be improved? Like, should I implement some interfaces to make it more maintainable or ensure availability of `set()` method.
6. What are your opinions?

Comment: Your not initializing the base class, you're default constructing it, then assigning values to it. If performance matters, that can be a big con.

Comment: You can just put a template constructor in the child class that forwards to the base class. Also, when passing in a string to a contructor like that, it's better to take it by value and move it into the member.

Comment: @super How can I do it? Can you show me.

Comment: Why are you trying to turn C++ into some other language you're used to?  C++ has its own idioms and paradigms -- trying to make C++ look like some other language will only confuse other C++ programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace your `super` method with a template constructor that forwards to the base class.

```
template <typename T>
struct Child : public T {
  int derivedA_ = 0;

  Child() = default;
  ~Child() = default;

  Child(int a) : derivedA_{a} {}

  template <typename... Args>
  Child(int a, Args&&... args) : T{std::forward<Args>(args)...}, derivedA_{a} {}
};
```

Now you can use it like so

```
auto c1 = Child<Parent>(23, 23, 3.5);
auto c2 = Child<AnotherParent>(243, "Hello, World!");
auto c3 = Child<Parent>(23, 42);
```

**Edit:**

Just a note on `AnotherParent`s constructor. Since you pass in the `std::string` by const ref you will always have to copy it into the member.

In that scenario, it's better to take the parameter by value. You will still at worst make one copy there too, but when we pass in an rvalue to the constructor we get a move instead of a copy.

```
AnotherParent(std::string a) : baseA_{std::move(a)} {}
```

Comment: What does it mean by forwarding? Can't I just pass the parameters to base class constructor?

Comment: You can, but forwarding will preserve the value category. It's a way to make sure that a temporary value get's moved instead of copied. Essentially it will avoid extra copies when possible.

Comment: And move? What does that do?

Comment: Move will "steal" the content from one object and move it into another, instead of copying the content from one object to another. So if you can get away with moving instead of copying you gain performance (in most cases).

Comment: When dealing with an `int`, it doesn't really matter. But when you're dealing with a `std::string` for example, a move is just copying the value of a pointer and a copy will have to read the whole string and copy it into the other object.

Comment: Will the old object be still useable after move (in case it is not a temporary object but a variable)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230446/discussion-between-mansoor-ahmed-memon-and-super).

Comment: No. Once moved from the old object is left empty (or more exact in a valid but unspecified state). Move will only happen automatically from a temporary object. If it's a variable you need to use `std::move` to move it explicitly like in the example with `AnotherParent`s constructor.